# Database already exist. Choose a Different Name using CreateDatabase()

Tags: c#, linq, mdf

I got an issue and learned something at the same time....

I created a DBML from an existing server database.

From the DBML I wanted to create local database (an .mdf file).  I created the database `using DataContext.CreateDatabase("C:\xxxx.mdf")` .

Then I decided to delete it (MANUALLY, which is a bad thing evidentally) because when I try to recreate the database with the same name (eventhough the files are deleted), I get the error  **Database already exist. Choose a Different Name using CreateDatabase()**

I tried looking through the registry, no luck... I tried searching the whole hard drive for the file.. no luck.

After googling, I found that you delete a database that was created with `CreateDatabase()` with `DeleteDatabase()`.... Then you can recreate the database again.

Well problem is, now I still can't recreate the old database because the system thinks the name already exists.

Is there a way to get rid of the reminents of the old databse file the "does not exist"

Comment: when you deleted it manually did you delete both the mdf and ldf? Also, what error do you get when you call DeleteDatabase() now?

Comment: When I try DeleteDatabase(), I get this: **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\xxxx.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share..**

Answer (score 7):

You need to open [master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) database via `server explorer` in Visual Studio (Add New Connection + Select `master` database) then add a `New query`, type  `Drop Database xxxx` and execute it. You can also use `Sql Server Management Studio.`

Comment: I encountered the same problem too. Is it possible to do what you suggested programmatically?

Comment: In case someone is wondering the same thing, yes, you can do this programatically. Simply connect to the database in your code, then send the appropriate SQL statement for execution (`drop database xxxx`).

Answer (score 3):

A solution (via [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1750469.aspx?Database%20already%20exists%20Choose%20a%20different%20database%20name%20)) is to use [SSEUtil](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3990) to detach the existing db:

```
try
{
    // open a connection to the database for test
}
catch (SystemException ex) // Change exception type based on your underlying data provider
{
    if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("already exists. choose a different database name"))
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(ex.Message, "database '(.*)' already exists.", 
           RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            String dbFileName = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = String.Format("{0}/Tools/SSEUtil.exe", 
              Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-d \"{0}\"", dbFileName);

            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1  I've encountered this problem when programmatically deploying SQL Server databases with Linq to SQL classes. Not sure why the database remains attached after the application exists, however this tool manages to detach the database. If anyone has ideas how to prevent this problem in the first place and therefore remove the need for this solution it would be great. Thanks for the solution by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fix for a localDB mess. Just connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB in SQL Mgmt. Studio/Visual Studio.

[image: SQL Server Connection]

Then delete the offender, checking "Close existing connections"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also actually had this same problem. Previously, I deleted
(cut) the database in mysqlserver2012 and copied it to my application folder. After I made my app I got this error, and solved it by removing the `Initial Catalog` part of my Connection String.

Your final connection string should look something like this:

`Data Source=<your server name>;AttachDbFileName=database path\databaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True" + ";User Instance=True" + ";Context Connection=False;`