# how to create master database?

Tags: c#, database

I created a .mdf database using DataContextand. Then I deleted the database files manually from the pc. 
Now I can't create a database with the same name and path using `DataContextInstance.CreateDatabase();` because somewhere the database still exists, and using `DataContextInstance.DeleteDatabase();` won't work. That's why I need the master database to drop the database.

How do I create a master database and drop my "myDBname" database?

Comment: hope this will help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775409/database-already-exist-choose-a-different-name-using-createdatabase

Comment: I saw it but there is no explanation how to do it..

Comment: do you have sql server manazment studio?

Comment: No. I want to do it through code, not manually

Answer (score 2):

The *master* database is already exists so no need to restore it. You may use ADO.NET provider API to drop a database.

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
{
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("drop database yourdbName", cn))
 {
  cn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cn.Close();
  }
 }
```

EDIT:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("drop database [07-02-2012]", cn))
{..}
```

You need to change the connection string and use `DataContext.DeleteDatabase()` method.

```
string cnstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=c:\file.mdf;Integrated Security=true";
MyDbContext dx = new MyDbContext(cnstr);
if (dx.DatabaseExists())
 {
   dx.DeleteDatabase();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this code but an exception is thrown at the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" line saying "Incorrect syntax near '07'." my database name is "07-02-2012" so I used it instead "empdb". do you know why?

Comment: @remi - Try Drop Database [07-02-2012]

Comment: Thanks, that solved the syntax problem. Now it throw exception at the same line saying "Cannot drop the database '07-02-2012', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Comment: What OS you have? if Win7 then start Visual studio with Admin privileges or may be the database is not exists.

Comment: I hava win7. I tried running visual studio as admin but still the same problem. In my uniqe case the database is not exists physically because I delete it from my pc but somewhere visual studio still think it's exists and the function `DataContextInstance.CreateDatabase();` won't work. anyway, even though I created a new database and tried your code I get the same exception

Comment: can it be because I created the database through the code using `myDataContextInstance.CreateDatabase`?

Answer (score 0):

so *SQL Server Management Studio* or in *Server Explorer* .. *Add New Connection* + *Select master database*, *new query* and *drop Database yourDB*.