# DbMigrator.Update resulting in a Database 'name' already exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using EF code first for a web api system but the use of a DbMigrator in the Configuration for my context results in a SqlException:

```
ystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Database 'name' already exists. Choose a different database name..
```

this is with the code:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(this);

        // This is required to detect changes.
        var pendingMigrationsExist = dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();

        if (pendingMigrationsExist)
        {
            dbMigrator.Update();
        }
    }
```

without the call to `dbMigrator.Update()` the seed method is not executed.

How do I get the seed method to run without this problem?
Removing the `dbMigrator.Update()` call allows the system to create the DB, but no data is seeded.

Note:
I am using a CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initialiser, and this is set withing the constructor of the context:

```
public MyContext() : base("name=myconnectionstringname")
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
}
```

Edit: add information on context:

```
public class TelephonyContext : DbContext
{
    private const string Key = "ddd412345fdee012ddd41e3456789012";
    private const string Iv = "fab41e34567fk012";

    public TelephonyContext()
        : base("name=telephony-connection")
    {
        var encryptedPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["telephony-pass"];
        var password = AesEncryption.Decrypt(encryptedPassword, Key, Iv);

        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = Database.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace("XXXXXX", password);

        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TelephonyContext>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SoftphoneUser> SoftphoneUserSet { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<InitialCall> InitialCallSet { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<CallAudit> CallAuditSet { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<RecordingErrorType> RecordingErrorTypeSet { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SourceApplication> SourceApplicationSet { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var history in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && (e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                        e.State == EntityState.Modified))
           .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
        {
            history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            if (history.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        var result = base.SaveChanges();
        foreach (var history in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                      .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory)
                                      .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
        {
            history.IsDirty = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    // todo need to sort this issue
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1506:AvoidExcessiveClassCoupling", Justification = "TODO need to sort this issue")]
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder != null)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SoftphoneUserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new InitialCallConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CallAuditConfiguration());

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SourceApplicationConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RecordingErrorTypeConfiguration());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

and seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(TelephonyContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("running in method Configuration.Seed()");

        var allRecordingErrorTypes = new List<RecordingErrorType>();

        foreach (RecordingErrorTypeEnumeration errorType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RecordingErrorTypeEnumeration)))
        {
            allRecordingErrorTypes.Add(new RecordingErrorType
            {
                ErrorTypeId = errorType,
                Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(RecordingErrorTypeEnumeration), errorType),
                Description = errorType.GetDescription()
            });
        }

        context.RecordingErrorTypeSet.AddOrUpdate(allRecordingErrorTypes.ToArray());

        var a = new SourceApplication { ApplicationId = 1, ApplicationName = "TelephonyService", IsActive = true, UpdatedBy = "System" };
        var b = new SourceApplication { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationName = "MortgagePayments", IsActive = true, UpdatedBy = "System" };
        var c = new SourceApplication { ApplicationId = 3, ApplicationName = "HomeInsurancePayments", IsActive = true, UpdatedBy = "System" };
        var d = new SourceApplication { ApplicationId = 4, ApplicationName = "CreditCardPayments", IsActive = true, UpdatedBy = "System" };

        context.SourceApplicationSet.AddOrUpdate(app =>
            new { app.ApplicationId, app.ApplicationName, app.IsActive, app.UpdatedBy }, a, b, c, d);
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: not solved yet, been sidetracked on another project, will come back to it next week.

Comment: Not got to the bottom of this, however, removing the dbMigrator code from the configuration object, and moving the seed data to a custom override o the CreateIfNotExists initialiser seems to have done the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database already exist. Choose a Different Name using CreateDatabase()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775409/database-already-exist-choose-a-different-name-using-createdatabase)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate the error. Here is my code:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MockApplicationUser.MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(this);

        // This is required to detect changes.
        var pendingMigrationsExist = dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();

        if (pendingMigrationsExist)
        {
            dbMigrator.Update();
        }
    }

    protected override void Seed(MockApplicationUser.MyContext context)
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] { new Product { Name = "Product1", rating = 1 }, new Product { Name = "Product1", rating = 1 }, new Product { Name = "Product1", rating = 1 } };
        context.Products.AddOrUpdate(products);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks identical to mine (with a less complex context) and that is why I am at a loss as to why mine is failing.  I drop the database manually then run an automated integration test (written as a unit test) that simply performs `using (var context = new MyContext()){context.Database.Initialize(true);}` and it all falls over in a heap

Comment: Would you mind posting your context and seed method?